# Rails: how do i change values in table from nil to string inside the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I update a `nil` value in my rails `User` database table?

There are three `:string` fields which are currently `nil`. And I'm trying to update these fields.

Here is an example of my rails console:

```
2.4.0 :002 > User.find(1)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, email: "antchamberlin.js@gmail.com", created_at: "2017-09-06 11:43:15", updated_at: "2017-09-08 07:42:48", username: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil> 
2.4.0 :003 > @user = User.username = ant
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ant' for main:Object
    from (irb):3
```

What is the correct terminal code I need to update the `username: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil` fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case:

```
@user = User.username = ant
```

You're saying, @user is equal to User.username, what at the same time is equal to ant, but what's `ant`? Rails will try to work with it as a local variable in your current scenario, that's why the message:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `ant' for main:Object

You need to use [update](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update), specify each attribute as a "key" and the corresponding new value as the key value, like:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.update(username: 'new username', first_name: 'new first_name', last_name: 'new last_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using **update** or **update_attributes** method to update AR model with new values to fields/columns.

```
user = User.find(1)
user.update_attributes(username: 'new username', first_name: 'new first_name')
# OR
user.update(username: 'new username', first_name: 'new first_name')
```

I think from your question you are getting **undefined method ant**. Please define ant variable and proceed for the update.

Answer (score 1):

```
user = User.find(1)

user.update(username: 'new username attribute goes here', first_name: 'new firstname attribute goes here')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion